# How can I use this in the left side of the object destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

(This question is not specific to Vue, but it is in a Vue project, that is why the strange use of the `this` in front of the functions and variables.)

I have a function that returns an object which is destructured into two variables:

```
  const { primaryNumber, typeOfExpression } = this.findPrimaryAndType(
    this.naturalExpressionYearOfBirth,
    this.gender,
  );
```

I don't want the variables to be `primaryNumber` and `typeOfExpression` any more, I want them to be `this.primaryNumber` and `this.typeOfExpression` which refer to my view data section.

I have found a crummy workaround using the code below:

```
  this.primaryNumber = primaryNumber;
  this.typeOfExpression = typeOfExpression;
```

But this can't be the best way of doing it! What should I do? If I add `this` in front of the variables inside the `{}` I get an error and if I remove the const it does not accept the `=` Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spell out the destructuring targets, instead of implicitly creating `const` variables:

```
({
  primaryNumber: this.primaryNumber,
  typeOfExpression: this.typeOfExpression
} = this.findPrimaryAndType(
  this.naturalExpressionYearOfBirth,
  this.gender,
));
```

Of course that's not very helpful in terms of conciseness. If those two properties are the only ones on the result object, you can however use `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(this, this.findPrimaryAndType(
  this.naturalExpressionYearOfBirth,
  this.gender,
));
```

Comment: Did **not** know you could use an object property as a destructuring target. Thought it had to be a variable.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue It can only be a variable in a variable declaration the same way you wouldn't do `var this.prop = 42;`, but just like `this.prop = 42` is fine, doing it in a destructuring assignment is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your *workaround* is the correct way to do this (at least from a pure Javascript perspective, not sure how Vue handles this). You can make it slightly shorter by using `Object.assign`:

```
const { primaryNumber, typeOfExpression } = this.findPrimaryAndType(
    this.naturalExpressionYearOfBirth,
    this.gender,
);
Object.assign(this, { primaryNumber, typeOfExpression });
```

Or, if you wanted to copy all the returned properties from `findPrimaryAndType` to the current instance, you could skip the destructuring altogether:

```
const { naturalExpressionYearOfBirth, gender } = this;
Object.assign(this, this.findPrimaryAndType(naturalExpressionYearOfBirth, gender));
```