# Is there a way to copy an entire object to a class's properties in one line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Right now I have a class that looks like this:

```js
class User {
  static collection = "users"

  public id?: string
  public email: string
  public name: string
  public token: string
  public username: string
  public image?: string
  public bio?: string
  public emailVerified?: boolean

  public createdAt: Date = new Date()
  public updatedAt?: Date

  constructor(params: InitParams<User>) {
    this.email = params.email
    this.name = params.name
    this.token = params.token
    this.username = params.username
    this.image = params.image
    this.bio = params.bio
    this.emailVerified = params.emailVerified
  }
}
```

Now `InitParams<User>` is a fancy type that matches the exact list of User's properties, without any methods that User might have. So the type guarantees that it has all the necessary properties to initialize `User`.

So I wanted to do something like this in the constructor:

```js
  constructor(params: InitParams<User>) {
    this = { ...params, ...this }
  }
```

But typescript says that that is illegal and I'm also pretty sure that then I would mess up the class in other ways. But just in case, is there a way to do this initialization in one line?

Comment: Try `Object.assign(this, params)`

Comment: @charlietfl I was thinking the same but that wouldn't stop `params` from accidentally overriding `createdAt` if that property happened to on the object. To be safe, you'd want to filter `params` keys by the keys of `InitParams<User>`

Comment: To be honest, if I was maintaining this code, I'd rather see the version in your question than some fancy, convoluted thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use this in the left side of the object destructuring assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643463/how-can-i-use-this-in-the-left-side-of-the-object-destructuring-assignment)

Comment: @charlietfl That does work (had the same idea and tried it out). The only downside is that typescript will no longer recognize the non-undefined properties of `User` to be definitely assigned in the constructor, so you have to change those to `public email!:string;` (with bang operator).

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326

Comment: @charlietfl thanks that does the trick. And phil, I don't have to worry about it overriding createdAt, because if I don't want that then I can just override createdAt myself again after Object.assin()